# UglifyJS Exclude Folder from Minifying JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, minify

I have a specific folder which contains 5 JavaScript files and I would like UglifyJS to ignore them all (i.e. not minify). I am aware of the exclude option, but not sure how to use it exactly in relation to the absolute path of the folder within the solution and how the format of the exclude string should be.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pattern option

`--pattern '**/*.js,!**/folder/*.js'`

Comment: In the the Uglify documents there isn't any pattern option ! https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).